# GDB: How to print/call parent functions from a child object?

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, printing, gdb

Basically, that is it. I do not manage to call some inherited functions/members from an object in GDB.

For instance, I have this line in my code:

```
41      std::cout << foo->size() << std::endl;
```

Which prints the size of 'foo' in console. But when I stop there with GDB and try to print it, I get this:

```
(gdb) print foo->size()
Couldn't find method foo::size
```

**EDIT**

foo declaration is:

```
class foo : public sc_core::sc_module { ... };
```

`sc_module` is a SystemC interface, where the method size() is. `sc_core` is the `namespace`. So when I try and get this:

```
(gdb) print (sc_module*)pipe.name()
No symbol "sc_module" in current context.
(gdb) print (sc_core::sc_object*)pipe.name()
A syntax error in expression, near `)pipe.name()'.
```

Is there a way that I can call that method from that point?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Try ((bar*)foo)->size()

Comment: I tried that before and I get the same error. I'll edit my question to add some more info.

Comment: After very long time, is there any progress? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can see this behavior if the method has been optimized out.  There may be other reasons as well.

The syntax error in the later example suggests that perhaps your gdb is old.  We've fixed bugs like this in more recent releases.